# javascript - Return the Variable name of an Object Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects similar to that bellow.

```
var object1 = {...},
var object2 = {...};

var array = [object1,object2];
```

I would like to be able to access the actual variable name later on in the script. For example, id like to return the actual string "object1" rather than return the actual object when using code similar the bellow for loop.

```
for (i in array) {
    var variableName = array[i];
}
```

I've considered using a key valued pair but haven quite figured out the particulars.

```
keyValuePair = [{name: "object1", object:object1}, {name:"object2",object:object2}];
```

I'm not sure if that is structured ideally nor how to access it.

Thoughts?

Comment: the variable name itself isn't actually part of the object, so there's no way to get back to it from the object unless you stored it within the object. however, it looks like you may be moving in a poor direction... usually not a good idea to have objects named like that, object1, object2, usually suggests that something is wrong with the design.

Comment: Why would you want the name anyway?

Comment: I need to be able to use its variable name at a later point  because I need to change a "name" property of the object at run time as it is created dynamically within the app. I thought itd be useful to simply use the objects variable name for clarity.

Comment: Related questions: [`[javascript] get name of variable`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+get+name+of+variable) (I hope you searched before :-/ )

Comment: *"I need to change a "name" property of the object at run time"* You only need a reference to the object for that (it doesn't matter how you get that reference). If you would provide a more complete example of the problem you are *actually* trying to solve, we could probably help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the variable name as property?

```
var object1 = {...},
var object2 = {...};

var array = { object1: object1, object2: object2 };
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create something like this:

```
var object1 = {...};
var object2 = {...};

var keyValuePair = {
  object1: object1,
  object2: object2
};
```

Then you can access `object1` like that: `keyValuePair["object1"]`.

Note that in ECMAScript 6 there's a shorter syntax:

```
var keyValuePair = {
  object1,
  object2
};
```